# React rendering recursion stops without error

Tags: recursion, reactjs

I've encountered a problem with rendering some elements in React.
(I use `ImmutableJS`)

```
renderComponents: function(components) {
    if(components.isEmpty()) return [];

    var table = [];

    components.map(function(component) {
      table.push(<ComponentTableElement key={ component.get('id') } data={ component } />);

      if(component.has('children')) {
        var children = component.get('children');
        table.concat(this.renderComponents(children));
      }
    });

    return table;
  },
```

As I looked for error, I found that `this.renderComponents(children)` doesn't return anything at all and the code somehow stops.

I mean before that line everything works ok, but then after this line, when i try to `console.log` something, it doesn't show up. And it doesn't even reach `return table`.

So what is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the function you pass to map, `this` refers to the `window` object, not to the current component instance, so `this.renderComponents` is undefined when you try to call it.

```
components.map(function(component) {
  this === window;
});
```

You can pass a value to use as `this` in the body of your function as the second parameter of `Array::map`.

```
components.map(function(component) {
  table.push(<ComponentTableElement key={ component.get('id') } data={ component } />);

  if(component.has('children')) {
    var children = component.get('children');
    // here, `this` refers to the component instance
    table.concat(this.renderComponents(children));
  }
}, this);
```

If you're using ES6, you can also use fat-arrow functions, which are automatically bound to `this`.

```
components.map((component) => {
  table.push(<ComponentTableElement key={ component.get('id') } data={ component } />);

  if(component.has('children')) {
    var children = component.get('children');
    // here, `this` refers to the component instance
    table.concat(this.renderComponents(children));
  }
});
```